# JavaFX video player using VLC slow performance

Tags: javafx, vlc, rtsp, vlcj

Currently I’m trying to develop RTSP video player, which can show many streams at one time (2, 4, 5 etc). It has to be fast and be able to run on Windows, Mac and Linux.

First app version has been written on Swing and VLC. Good performance, ability to play many streams at one time on slow PC. But not impressive UI and video playing is unsupported on Mac

So, after a lot of researching I stopped on JavaFX and VLC. Great UI, support on all platforms, but performance issues on slow PCs.

Here is simple project which can play one video: https://github.com/costello/vpfx
(don’t forget to set your media link in class java/app/AppController.java, line 22)

Unfortunately it’s using too much CPU, even if I play only one video. I tried to play 2 or 4 videos (from different RTSP streams), completely nightmare.

Here is CPU usage graph on PC with Intel® Pentium® Processor E5300  (2M Cache, 2.60 GHz, 800 MHz FSB) and integrated video card: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVzIq.jpg

```
vlcj version: 3.0.1 
VLC version: 2.1.5
Java: 7 and 8 (java fx 2.2 and java fx 8), same result.
```

Found this OpenGL discussion: [How to use OpenGL in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946030/how-to-use-opengl-in-javafx)

But I don’t know how to use OpenGL to render image from given RGB array and even I don’t know will it help.

Comment: You really need to make sure you are rendering using hardware acceleration, but even then there is a limit to how much resource is available to do that - even if you can hardware accelerate one stream, doing it for five may be impossible. Also, your implementation is prone to corrupt video memory because of your use of Platform.runLater in your render code (you access the native video buffer in an unsynchronised way). vlcj + JavaFX8 is a difficult problem.

Comment: I use a Swing app for vlcj, with my JavaFX components (e.g. menus) hosted inside a JFXPanel. Not ideal.

Comment: @caprica What about Mac support in your solution?

Comment: Mac support on Jdk7+ is also difficult, you have to render the video yourself (again, find a way to hardware accelerate it), but at least you won't have a synchronisation problem. And yet again, doing five streams that way (in hardware) is likely unfeasible.

Comment: Hopefully not not being a dead thread, @costello, did you find a solution here ? I am also using VLC to open video media file and JavaFX to display the frames. Did you find a better way of streaming videos ?

Comment: @Victor unfortunately, I didn't find any solution for JavaFX, so we decided to use VLC + swing and as result app was able to play up to 32 videos simultaneously (on MBP Late 2013). One restriction - we were not able to add any listeners or catch some mouse events on video area, but performance was perfect. However, this was  almost 5 years ago, I don't know what Swing, VLC and JavaFX can offer now. I hope this helped and to be honest, I accidentally opened this topic. Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @costello Thanks for the reply ! I have continued on the same path and the tweak I have added (and is still work in progress) is making vlc as external process. I want to effectively open vlcj in another process because after some playing time it is crashing. So, my issue is the crash that occur after ~5 days of playing which was a showstopper. I am not solving the crash issue, but I will be able to manage a process restart easier (mainly RMI calls). I do not use vlcj on multiple streams, so I am ok with the performance.

Comment: @Victor nice to hear that! It looks like you have memory leak, I had this as well. Switching to Swing solved everything, but you can try jProfiler or VisualVM to investigate memory, can be very useful.