# How to play a video in Slick2D?

Tags: java, video, lwjgl, slick2d

So, last day, I've got a really disturbing problem... I tried all methods, all libraries I've founded, all things can be imagined, but it doesn't work....

Please, did someone know a simple method for play video in Slick2D ? (I know it's an outdated one but I really like this library :D)

Really, if anyone know it, it would be REALLY helpful.Thanks in advance :P

Here a list of what I've tried :
Xuggler (3.4), JMF, TWL, YUNPM (0.7x && 0.8x), vlcj (3.10.1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy way" doing this. Especially because the library isn't supported anymore and it is not intended to support that functionality. If you have the knowledge you might be able to integrate one of your solutions, for example vlcj but it definitly will not be simple.

Maybe there is a work around for you if it's a short video you could create an animation with a spritesheet.

As well you might be able to use [JavaFX Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm#CJAHFAHJ). It depends a little bit on your project and what you intend to do.

Comment: Well, I think you've got right. But then how to import JavaFX Media in an OpenGL context ?
But it seems it's possible to do it with LWJGL (Because as you know, Slick2D is based on LWJGL) so maybe if I ask you "LWJGL" instead of "Slick2D", maybe you've got someting interesting ?

Thanks, for your quick answer :D

Comment: You could for example embed your Slick2D application inside of a JavaFX application. 

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946030/how-to-use-opengl-in-javafx?rq=1

As far as i know it's possible in lwjgl but still not that simple. From my opinion at least it is not easier than the solutions you already tried. Maybe this is useful for you if you can get it to work:

http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=2516.0