How to integrate OpenGL surface from SDL2/GLFW into a JavaFX application?
I'm building an OpenGL application and would like to use JavaFX for the GUI. Currently, I'm using SDL2 as the windowing system. I'm familiar with using JNI to call Java methods from C++ and vice versa.
My question is: How can I obtain the OpenGL render surface pointer from SDL2/GLFW and pass it to a JavaFX application for display?
I've seen examples of using PixelBuffer in JavaFX for rendering surfaces. This seems like a promising approach for communication between C++ OpenGL and JavaFX. However, I'm unsure about the specific steps involved in integrating them.

Did you see some of the suggestions from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946030/how-to-use-opengl-in-javafx The accepted answer seems to be outdated, but the newer ones seem to have some alternatives.

@matt Thank you for your suggestion. This question seems focus on java and opengl java bindings. But what I interesting in is just binding the opengl surface to javafx

I haven't worked with GLFW for some time, but as far as I remember glfw always operates on a window. But what you actually want is to create a OpenGL context for a non window surface. This is certainly possible with whatever API the OS provides (wgl/egl/...), but I'm not sure if you can achieve this with GLFW.

It is not OpenGL, but vlcj-javafx implements an ImageViewVideoSurface that allows rendering of a video surface that is generated by the native VLC application (via VLCJ).  It is based on the PixelBuffer as mentioned in your question.  Perhaps a similar implementation, but with an OpenGL renderer rather than a VLC renderer could be used.  Maybe a project linked from an answer that @matt linked would do that.

https://www.lwjgl.org/ uses GLFW it might be handy to look at what they're doing.
